# How to create an scaling animation in Kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, scale, kineticjs

I have the following code that is supposed to scale up a shape on mouseover and then scale it back to its original size on mouseout. I have a few problems:

1. How do I change the scale amount?
2. How do I end the animation in a certain time?
3. How do I do 1 and 2 without causing a glitch.
4. When the mouse pointer passes over the shape fast, some frames jump suddenly. How do I fix that?

All I need is a shape that get's bigger slowly when it is moused over, and then returns to its original size when mouse is out.

```
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="js/kinetic.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        function zoomHex() {
        }
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 500,
            height: 500
        });
        var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var hex = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
            x: 250,
            y: 250,
            sides: 6,
            radius: 80,
            fill: '#00D2FF',
            stroke: '#00D2FF',
            strokeWidth: 30,
            lineJoin: 'round'
        });
        var zoomIn = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
            var period = 1000;
            var duration = 1000;
            zoomAmount = 1;
            var scale =frame.time / period;
            hex.setScale(frame.time / period + zoomAmount);
            if(frame.time > duration) {
                zoomIn.stop();
                this.frame.time = 0;
            }
        }, shapesLayer);
        var zoomOut = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
            var period = 1000;
            var duration = 1000;
            zoomAmount = 2;
            hex.setScale(frame.time / period - zoomAmount);
            if(frame.time > duration) {
                zoomOut.stop();
                this.frame.time = 0;
            }
        }, shapesLayer);
        hex.on('mouseover', function() {
            zoomIn.start();
            //zoomIn.stop();
        });
        hex.on('mouseleave', function() {
            zoomOut.start();
            //zoomOut.stop();
        });
        shapesLayer.add(hex);
        stage.add(shapesLayer);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, I would suggest using a `Kinetic.Tween` instead of a `Kinetic.Animation`

See this tutorial for basic tween usage: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-linear-transition-tutorial-with-kineticjs/

```
var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
  node: hex, 
  duration: 1, // <--2) How do I end the animation in a certain time?
  scaleX: 1.5 // <-- 1) How do I change the scale amount?
  scaleY: 1.5 // <-- 1) How do I change the scale amount?
});

//3) How do I do 1 and 2 without causing a glitch.
//4) When the mouse pointer passes over the shape fast, some frames jump suddenly.
hex.on('mouseover', function() {
  tween.play();
});
hex.on('mouseleave', function() {
  tween.reverse();
});
```

So when you `mouseover` the hex shape, the tween will play forward and tween the scale to **1.5** (from 1.0 which is the default scale). When you `mouseleave` the tween will reverse back to the original state of the hex shape.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/nPssw/)

**NOTE:** Technically, you should be able to use the `scale` property instead of `scaleX` and `scaleY` like this:

```
var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
  node: hex, 
  duration: 1, //time in seconds
  scale: 1.5 //should scale both x and y
});
```

But for some reason, it didn't work for me. You can give it a shot though if you'd like.